# Rvest returning empty values and can't figure out why

Tags: r, rvest

I have a pretty templatized for this kind of thing and I've never seen it not work.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
library(zoo)

rivals_url <- paste0("https://rivals.com/prospect_rankings/rivals250/2021")

t300 <- map_df(rivals_url, ~.x %>% read_html %>%
                 html_nodes(".position .pos , .last-name , .first-name") %>%
                 html_text() %>% 
                 str_trim %>% 
                 str_split("   ") %>% 
                 matrix(ncol = 3, byrow = T) %>% 
                 as.data.frame)
```

When I run it, it just returns an empty set of values. Is there something specific about where I'm pulling from that causes this. For example, this script works fine:

```
espn_url <- paste0("http://www.espn.com/college-sports/football/recruiting/playerrankings/_/view/rn300")

t300 <- map_df(espn_url, ~.x %>% read_html %>%
                      html_nodes("td:nth-child(3), td:nth-child(8), Strong, .colhead td:nth-child(2)") %>%
                      html_text() %>% 
                      str_trim %>% 
                      str_split("   ") %>% 
                      matrix(ncol = 3, byrow = T) %>% 
                      as.data.frame)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site has a public facing API you can query directly:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(dplyr)

dat <- fromJSON("https://n.rivals.com/api/v1/ranks/4408/prospects?start=0&position=ALL%20POSITIONS&pageSize=250")

dat$prospects %>%
  as_tibble()

# A tibble: 250 x 26
       id first_name last_name name  position_abbrev~ stars prospect_url height weight verified_height verified_weight city  hometown highschool profile_image_u~
    <int> <chr>      <chr>     <chr> <chr>            <int> <chr>         <dbl>  <dbl> <lgl>           <lgl>           <chr> <chr>    <chr>      <chr>           
 1 232205 "Maason"   Smith     Maas~ DT                   5 https://n.r~     77    297 NA              NA              Houma Houma, ~ Terrebonne https://images.~
 2 209086 "JC"       Latham    JC L~ OT                   5 https://n.r~     78    310 NA              NA              Brad~ Bradent~ IMG Acade~ https://images.~
 3 216686 "Korey"    Foreman   Kore~ SDE                  5 https://n.r~     77    254 TRUE            FALSE           Coro~ Corona,~ Centennial https://images.~
 4 234618 "Amarius"  Mims      Amar~ OT                   5 https://n.r~     79    300 NA              NA              Coch~ Cochran~ Bleckley ~ https://images.~
 5 210175 "Caleb"    Williams  Cale~ DUAL                 5 https://n.r~     73    200 NA              NA              Wash~ Washing~ Gonzaga    https://images.~
 6 208999 "J.T."     Tuimoloau J.T.~ SDE                  5 https://n.r~     76    275 NA              NA              Bell~ Bellevu~ Eastside ~ https://images.~
 7 210587 "Brock"    Vandagri~ Broc~ PRO                  5 https://n.r~     75    198 NA              NA              Boga~ Bogart,~ Prince Av~ https://images.~
 8 234013 "Tommy "   Brockerm~ Tomm~ OT                   5 https://n.r~     78    288 NA              NA              Fort~ Fort Wo~ All Saint~ https://images.~
 9 237486 "Ty"       Thompson  Ty T~ DUAL                 5 https://n.r~     76    203 NA              NA              Gilb~ Gilbert~ Mesquite   https://images.~
10 194402 "Camar"    Wheaton   Cama~ RB                   5 https://n.r~     73    190 NA              NA              Garl~ Garland~ Lakeview ~ https://images.~
# ... with 240 more rows, and 11 more variables: state_abbreviation <chr>, school_id <int>, sport_school_id <int>, school_name <chr>, school_commits_url <chr>,
#   recruit_year <int>, big_college_logo <chr>, status <chr>, commit_date <chr>, rank <int>, rank_change <int>
```

Comment: Also a question for you. How do you know where to find that URL you used?

Comment: Okay I'm going Inspect -> Click on the Network tab -> But now I don't see anything that looks even remotely like the URL you have above

Comment: Make sure to reload the page while the network activity is open and filter by XHR to see what json data has been fetched.  Then you can determine the URL by looking at the headers.

Comment: I think I'm getting the hang of this, but I have one more question. On this page: 
https://n.rivals.com/search#?formValues=%7B%22sport%22:%22Football%22,%22recruit_year%22:2021,%22prospect_profiles.stars%22:%7B%22range%22:%22gte%22,%22number%22:4%7D,%22page_number%22:1,%22page_size%22:50%7D

I find the data I'm looking for in a file called `people` but when I plug the API header in the script you posted above I don't see the variable on the list:

`https://n.rivals.com/api/v1/people`

Comment: That's a bit trickier and well into new question territory but the search function is sending a POST request with the query parameters as a payload so you can't see what's happening by inspecting the URL alone.

Comment: But it is possible to get the information I'm looking for? If so, I'll do what you mentioned and write a new question

Comment: Try `fromJSON("https://n.rivals.com/api/v1/people?search[member]=Prospect&search[sport]=Football&search[recruit_year]=2021&search[prospect_profiles.stars][range]=gte&search[prospect_profiles.stars][number]=4&search[page_number]=1&search[page_size]=50")`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code does not work is because you are trying to scrape a dynamic page.  You will need to use a package such as RSelenium.  The below code should work:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
library(RSelenium)

rivals_url <- paste0("https://rivals.com/prospect_rankings/rivals250/2021")

#####Open remote browser

rD <- rsDriver(browser = "chrome")
remDr <- rD[["client"]]

remDr$navigate(rivals_url)
rivals_page <- read_html(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]])

##### Scrape target page and format results

 t300 <- rivals_page %>%
   html_nodes(".position .pos , .last-name , .first-name") %>%
   html_text() %>%
   str_trim %>%
   str_split("   ") %>%
   matrix(ncol = 3, byrow = T) %>%
   as.data.frame %>%
   `colnames<-`(c("Last Name", "First Name", "Position"))

##### Close remote browser and terminate related processes
 
remDr$close()
rD$server$stop()
rm(rD, remDr)
gc()

system("taskkill /im java.exe /f", intern=FALSE, ignore.stdout=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to read all about RSelenium!